# Support Vector Machines - Kernel Functions/Soft Margin SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I had these questions in an exam today. State True or False and explain.

1. If k1(.,.) and k2(.,.) are two valid kernel functions, then if h = k1 - k2, is h(.,.) a valid kernel function?
2. A standard soft margin SVM is used to classify data set. We have a fixed C parameter. Two different algorithms A1 and A2 are used to obtain the support vector set {$S: \alpha_i > 0$}. Call them S1 and S2. Is S1 = S2 in all cases? Assume both algorithm use the same kernel function.

I had no clue about these questions. I only knew about kernel functions, but not about operations between kernel functions. I only guessed: as kernel function need to be positive semi definite (PSD), the difference between two kernel functions need not be PSD. Hence FALSE.  For the second one, I guessed as $\alpha_i$ can be different among the two algorithms, the number of support vectors can differ as well. Hence FALSE again.

Comment: Imagine k1 = k2. Then, h = 0 everywhere. Its integral cannot be 1, which is a requirement of kernel functions.